# accees to ndb model from behave

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, bdd

I assume this might be impossible but I've been wondering...

I'm building a flask application (running on google app engine)
and i'm using behave as the BDD tool.
it all works well if I keep everything separated through the browser automation.

what I want is to have a peek at the data structure (in my case, so I can check my simulated users attributes). when I try to :

```
from application.models import MyUserModel
```

I get the following error

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/behave", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('behave==1.2.3', 'console_scripts', 'behave')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 111, in main
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 474, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 477, in run_with_paths
    self.load_hooks()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 437, in load_hooks
    exec_file(hooks_path, self.hooks)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 283, in exec_file
    execfile(filename, globals, locals)
  File "/Users/ido/Documents/workspace/talknet-0.2.02/src/features/environment.py", line 13, in <module>
    import application
  File "/Users/ido/Documents/workspace/talknet-0.2.02/src/application/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import g, Flask, render_template
  File "/Users/ido/Documents/workspace/talknet-0.2.02/src/lib/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

I know my features and steps are not running in appserver context.
but I'm not there yet. this is an import issue...

is there a way around this ???

Comment: It looks like you are including the source code of Flask (as opposed to installing it). Are you also including the source code of its requirements (e.g., Jinja2, Werkzeug)?

Comment: yes I am. it's all there under lib/ and works well under appserver but not under testbed

Answer (score 1):

To fix the exception in the example you provided add:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

To your `app.yaml` file.

See more info here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: it's all there and works well under appserver but not under testbed